# Does a CircularProgressBar stop by default in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, kotlin-stateflow

I'm getting data from an external API. In the ViewModel class I collect the data as below:

```
private val state: MutableState<Resource<List<Item>>> = mutableStateOf(Resource(emptyList()))

viewModelScope.launch {
    repository.getItems().collect { resource ->
        state.value = resource
    }
}
```

In the activity class I use:

```
val resource = viewModel.state.value

when(resource) {
    is Resource.Loading -> Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        CircularProgressIndicator() // Starts spinning
    }
    is Resource.Success -> LazyColumn {
        items(
            resource.data
        ) { item ->
            ItemCard(item = item)
        }
    }
    is Resource.Failure -> Text(
        text = resource.message,
    )
}
```

As soon as the resource starts loading the progress bar **starts** spinning. Once I got the data, when the resource is success, it gets displayed in CardView and the progress bar **stops** spinning. I have never added in my code something that stops that from spinning. How is this possible? Does it remain still active (spinning) and I need to stop it my self programmatically, or is it a automatically stopped? How to handle this situation?

Comment: `CircularProgressIndicator` is added to the view hierarchy when `resource` has a value of `Resource.Loading`. As soon as the value of `resource` is changed, it is removed from the view hierarchy and replaced by another view: `LazyColumn` or `Text`. This is exactly how `when` works: only one of the branches adds a view to the view hierarchy at a time.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov Hey Philip, thanks for commenting. So you say that there is no CircularProgressIndicator that has to be stopped, it's done by default, right? If so, you might also consider answering the question as it helped me understand the concept.

Comment: This is what declarative programming is we don't do all the work manually (Imperative style) instead we just say how our UI should look like at each state and compose will show/hide what needs to be done and that's the major advantage and as Philip said it can be only at one state in `when`